# Should answers ignoring the country tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, country-tags, answers

If a question provides a country tag, and further specifies in the question body that the question applies to that country, should answers that address the question in regards to other countries be allowed, or should they be removed?

I can understand removing (or at least downvoting) the answers, since if I'm asking about taxes in Australia, German tax laws are completely irrelevant. The answer doesn't actually answer the question asked.

I can also understand keeping the answers, since others may have the same question about the same topic, just in a different country, and these answers may help those people (and we don't end up with the same question posted 10 times with identical text and a different country tag each time).

What's the consensus for these types of answers?

Comment: Is there a specific example question that you are concerned about?

Comment: @BenMiller I asked based on https://money.stackexchange.com/q/99488/36669, a Canada question that had two (now-deleted) US-centric answers - one which ignored the Canada tag entirely, and one which acknowledged the answer doesn't apply to Canada and somebody else could address Canada in a different answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. And I’ve encouraged members to not ‘answer as if a US question until we know otherwise.’ When a question really needs a country tag, a comment is appropriate and 24 hours to let the OP update the question. Nothing wrong with seeing if OP discloses country in other questions or in profile. I did learn the hard way that VPNs can give a false origin if we look at the OP’s IP address, so that’s off limits.

Questions with answers that violate your suggestion should be flagged and the mis-countried answer deleted. (And I did just that with the linked question).